# validate birthdate in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to validate a birthdate by JavaScript function.

This is the JavaScript function:

```
function dat() {

    var myDate1 = document.getElementById("d").value;

    var month  = myDate1.substring(0, 2) - 1;
    var date   = myDate1.substring(3, 5) - 0;
    var year   = myDate1.substring(6, 10) - 0;
    var myDate = new Date(year, month, date);
    var today  = new Date();

    if (myDate1 > today) {
        document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("d").style.borderColor = "green";
    }
    else if (myDate1 < today) {
        document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML = myDate1;
        document.getElementById("d").style.borderColor = "red";
    }

    if (document.getElementById("d").value == "") {
        document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML = "This Field  Is Required";
        document.getElementById("d").style.borderColor = "red";

    }
}
```

and this is the html input

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="d">Date Of Birth</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="d" id="d" 
           onKeyUp="dat()" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
    <p>
    <div style="color:red" id="dd"></div>
    </p>
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
</div>
```

It always returns (the date is left) even when I put the date of tomorrow.

what is the problem ?

Comment: You should really format your code better. It's pretty hard to read as is.

Comment: `myDate1 > today` will always be true when `myDate1` is in the future. Are you sure that you don't have simply mixed up the comparison order and meant `myDate < today`?

Comment: Both `date` and `year` would be `NaN` with that code

Comment: it is always false even I put myDate < today or even I insert a future date

Comment: What exactly are you trying to validate about the date? What you probably out to be validating is the date format, but that doesn't seem to be your idea of validating a date.

Comment: you should use some date plugin, relying on date entered manually can give unexpected results.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  - I am? shouldn't the date be in the RFC3339 standard, i.e. `2016-12-22`, meaning the OP gets `20` for the month, probably something like `6-` for the date etc ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  -> https://jsfiddle.net/zxn4hdv6/

Comment: @adeneo: I missed the `type=date`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - and the datepicker part (in supporting browsers) won't work with a `onKeyUp` event handler either

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing the date to the input value, not the date object.

```
var myDate1= document.getElementById("d").value;  <-- You are using this
var myDate= new Date(year,month,date);            <-- Not this
var today = new Date();

if (myDate1>today)
    ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dates in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, you could simply use `Date.parse` instead of writing your own date parser.

Do this:

```
var utime = Date.parse(yourDate)
if (utime == NaN)  {
    alert('Invalid date');
} else if (utime < new Date()) {
    alert('Valid birth date! It\'s in the past');
} else {
   alert('Invalid birth date! It\'s in the future');
}
```

## Warning!

As stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> ### Fall-back to implementation-specific date formats
>
> The ECMAScript specification states: If the String does not conform to
>   the standard format the function may fall back to any
>   implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing
>   algorithm. Unrecognizable strings or dates containing illegal element
>   values in ISO formatted strings shall cause `Date.parse()` to return
>   NaN.
>
> However, invalid values in date strings not recognized as ISO format
>   as defined by ES5 may or may not result in NaN, depending on the
>   browser and values provided, e.g.:
>
> ```
> // Non-ISO string with invalid date values
> new Date('23/25/2014');
> ```
>
> will be treated as a local date of 25 November, 2015 in Firefox 30 and
>   an invalid date in Safari 7. However, if the string is recognized as
>   an ISO format string and it contains invalid values, it will return
>   NaN in all browsers compliant with ES5:
>
> ```
> // ISO string with invalid values
> new Date('2014-25-23').toISOString();
> // returns "RangeError: invalid date" in all es5 compliant browsers
> ```
>
> SpiderMonkey's implementation-specific heuristic can be found in
>   jsdate.cpp. The string "10 06 2014" is an example of a non–conforming
>   ISO format and thus falls back to a custom routine. See also this
>   rough outline on how the parsing works.
>
> ```
> new Date('10 06 2014');
> ```
>
> will be treated as a local date of 6 October, 2014 and not 10 June,
>   2014. Other examples:
>
> ```
> new Date('foo-bar 2014').toString();
> // returns: "Invalid Date"
>
> Date.parse('foo-bar 2014');
> // returns: NaN
> ```

Comment: If you want to rely on undocumented behavior, yes, and worry about whether it's interpreted in UTC or local time (which can affect what day you end up seeing). For instance, while `Date.parse("01/06/2015")` gives you Jan 6th 2015 on Firefox, `Date.parse("06/01/2015")` gives you June **5th** on Firefox in some places. (Because of DST, and so UTC and locale time are offset.) Chrome uses UTC for that same string.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. This is not a secure way of doing it at all, the best option would be using a date/time library, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), but it does exactly what OP code is doing.